# Is it possible to use etckeeper with a single shared git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, etc, etckeeper

I noticed that several people have recommended using **etckeeper** to apply version control to my /etc directory.

It appears to me that the default install puts a repository on the same machine as the /etc you are trying to manage.  This works fine for version control, but doesn't give the added benefit of making an off-server backup of the files - or allow me to duplicate portions of /etc from one source machine to another.

Is it possible to **share a single git repository** on a central admin machine, so that etckeeper on each server stores its data in the same place?

(I am doing a similar thing now with svn and some custom scripts to commit and revert files, but I have to remember to commit them when I make changes.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, use install etckeeper, configured for git in /etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf.  Follow etckeeper's install method for your distro or from source.

Soon, you'll have a /etc/.git

Now on on your server, make sure you have a (safe) repo to push to...

```
 # ssh faruser@farhost     
 # mkdir somedir && cd somedir && git init && chmod 700 .git
 # exit
```

Now on the initial host, push your local repo to the server via ssh:

```
# cd /etc && git push faruser@farhost:somedir
```

Somedir can of course be relative in this case (following ssh convention)

Do this any time you make a change that affects /etc (and is snarfed into /etc/.git by etckeeper) and you'll have both local and off-machine repos for your machine.

Or set up passwordless ssh and make a hook in /etc/etckeeper/commit.d/ so it happens automagically if the machine is always connected.

Comment: This looks great. Is there a way to have the local repository stored in a subdirectory of the remote one? I'd like to do something similar, using a single remote repository to store the (separate) configurations for several servers.

Comment: can `git push` works towards your created git repo ? probably you need create bare repo in somedir

the hook under commit.d is really good idea, I like it

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to add a remote branch configuration to map the master branch of etckeeper repository from each server to a branch on the remote repository. To do that you can run the following commands on each server:

```
cd /etc
git branch -m master $HOSTNAME
git remote add origin git@git.example.com:path/to/single/repo.git
git push -u origin master:$HOSTNAME
```

After this setup, subsequent `git push` will send changes from each server master branch to the dedicated server branch on the central repository.

Although the branches will not have a common starting point, this allows to easily compare the same file from two different branches, representing two different servers, by running:

```
git diff origin/server1 origin/server2 -- file
```

This can be combined with the automated setup suggested by [jojoo](https://serverfault.com/a/474769/275266).

Comment: git push -u origin master:$HOSTNAME does not work here. Remote repo is an empty bare repo.

    error: src refspec master does not match any.

Answer (score 2):

How to do it automatically, the full story:

Create the file /etc/etckeeper/commit.d/60-push (dont forget to chmod+x it) on the clients.

```
#!/bin/sh
git push central_server:/var/git/client_name.git master
```

central_server is defined in the ssh config, see below. /var/git/client_name.git is the directory on the central server, containing the git repo.

The ~/.ssh/config from root(!) should contain something like this:

```
host central_server
Hostname 192.168.0.1
User etckeeper #a user on the central server 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/custom_key # key is in authorized_keys in
             #etcpeeper@central_server:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then you need to init the git repo on the central_server

```
mkdir /var/git/client_name.git
su etckeeper
cd /var/git/client_name.git
git --bare init
```

Test it with a minor edit in /etc and then a etckeeper commit "test push'ing".

Answer (score 1):

That's not the point. If you want to distribute configuration widely, you set up another repository in addition to each machine's local repo, and have each machine [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) from it as needed. What this does is allow each machine to deviate (branch, really) and retain revision control.

Comment: Not sure how to do this (second repository).  Can you elaborate?

Comment: You probably need to clone one of the repos onto your "central repo"; you only need one. From there you can make changes, and then each of the servers can cherry-pick the patches stored in a revision. How you set it up initially varies between DSCMs. For git, see http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/gittutorial.html

Answer (score -2):

You really don't want to make etckeeper your backup policy. While having a copy of your config files would be nice, it's hardly enough to qualify as a disaster recovery plan.

Focus on having real backups of your system instead. The simplist could be a cronjob for feeding a tarball to tape... oh, right. No one uses tapes anymore. Okay, a cronjob to [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/examples.html) *all* your files to a [dedicated NAS](http://www.lacie.com/us/products/range.htm?id=10007). For more robust backup solutions, take a look at [Amanda](http://amanda.zmanda.com/) and [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/).

And for the case of academics, I was able to [push](http://github.com/guides/git-cheat-sheet) my etckeeper repo up to [github](https://github.com/) just like any other git repo.

Comment: Nobody's talking about making this a backup policy.  But in my experience it IS convenient to have everything in one place, on a more secure server.

Comment: Then I misunderstood. If what you're really looking for is a means to centrally store and distribute your systems configuration, then maybe Puppet (http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet) would be of some help there.

Comment: for an example: we're pushing all our configurations to one host. there runs a trac, which is used for visualizing the config changes (and of course write tickets, if something doesn't work, ...) imo it's super-convinient, i can for an example compare the crontabs from all our hosts with a few clicks.